# Dynamically update SQL column Names

Tags: sql

I have a table where 36 months of data is delivered with 36 columns for the date. They are labeled as 36, 35, 35 , etc..
Is there a way to change the column names based on another table that has the mapping for 36 to be 2/28/22.
The dates will roll forward each month, and my goals was to have the mapping table dictate the column names.

Comment: I would suggest to think about this table structure once more. It looks very suspicious

Comment: This sounds a *very* bad idea. Databases are very good with rows of data. What have you got against rows? How would you envisage this working with 10 years' of data?

Comment: I have no flexibility with the table structure and it will always be 36 months of data.

Comment: It sounds like you should be *aliasing* the columns in your reporting tool/front end. If you want to alias in the actual query you'll need dynamic SQL, which is very product-specific.

Comment: And what will happen when the mapping of column36 changes? What will happen to the data in your table?  Can you share more details of what you are actually doing with this (The only thing I can think of that you are avoiding the use of pivot)

Comment: Changing column names every month will result in broken queries/reports every month, which in turn will result in unhappy consumers. This is officially a bad thing.

Comment: If 36 = 2/28/22, what does 35 and 34 and 1 equal?